# How to add and execute .sh script to folder in windows?

Tags: bash, shell, directory, command-prompt

I am having some difficulty wrapping my head around how I would implement this script that adds frame labels to avi videos. An example I was given is as follows:

“Example:
$ ./add_frame_caption.sh ./data_folder/ avi

Which would add labels to all avi videos in the data_folder.”

My question is how do I execute/implement this script within a folder on Win 10, such as a folder in my downloads?

The script is as follows:
file name =
add_frame_caption.sh

```
root_folder=$1
file_ext=$2
for i in $(ls $root_folder*.$file_ext)
do
    output_name=$root_folder$(basename $i .$file_ext)_frame_label.$file_ext
    ffmpeg -i $i -vf "drawtext=fontfile=Arial.ttf: text='%{frame_num}': start_number=1: x=(w-tw)/2: y=h-(2*lh): fontcolor=black: fontsize=20: box=1: boxcolor=white: boxborderw=5" -c:a copy $output_name
done
```

Thanks

Tried adding script through command prompt but had issues.

Comment: _but had issues_ is not exactly the best problem description I've ever seen .....

Comment: The number one first thing you should do is check your script with [shellcheck](https://shellcheck.net) -- that will save people like me a lot of time explaining basic mistakes, and may provide enough information to fix whatever problem you are really having.

Comment: Obvious questions: what do you mean by "within a folder"? In what way is the version of Windows relevant? What issues did you have **exactly**?

Comment: In the text of your question, you say _add **frame labels** to videos_. In the title of the question, you say _add **script** to folder_, whatever this is supposed to mean. Perhaps you first make up your mind, what you actually want to do, and then provide an understandable question for it.

Comment: See also [here](https://solveforum.com/forums/threads/solved-why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead.86986/) for your use of `ls`.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of clarification; this is my first time posting on stack and I realized I was not very clear on my question. I do not know how to implement this script that adds frame labels to avi videos. @user1934428, the script I want to execute adds frame labels to videos.

Comment: I want to have this script work for avi videos located in a certain folder within C:/users/downloads. I mentioned windows 10 in case it makes any difference on accomplishing this compared to a macOS or linux machine.

Comment: My issue is that I do not know how to go about adding this script to work for videos in a specified folder. How would I use and execute this script is my question.

Comment: Your script suffers from elegance in that it requires that `$1` is terminated by a `/`, and of course - as I said - your use of `ls` is unnecessary and counterproductive. If you would write the loop as `for i in "$root_folder"/*."$file_ext"`, you would get rid of both problems, and it would even work with folders having a whitespace in their name.

Comment: Okay, that's a good idea.